# SharePoint Online - Add ID column to a AllItems view with link

Tags: sharepoint-online

On a *modern* site list in SharePoint Online - is it possible to add the ID column and make it clickable?

In SharePoint 2010 you could use Designer to modify the view adding `<FieldRef Name="ID" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>`. This does not appear to work anymore on a modern site in SP Online.

How can I replicate the same with SP Online?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that the Column Formatting : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting option is disabled on the ID field in a modern list/library. If you are in a position to develop customizations using SPFx, the SPFx field customizer extension might be a way to go but i am not sure if it will work on the ID field in list/library as you need to assign the ClientComponentID property on the field to enable it : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer

Answer (score 0):

In the list with modern experience, we can add the ID column in the AllItems view but we cannot make the ID column clickable.

We can edit the current view and add the ID column for modern experience.

[image]